# Managing (Deleting) Multiple Python Environment

Tags: python

I understand this is probably a duplicated question, but I still have a hard time figuring out what to do in my case.

The following is my Python kernel:

[image]

While I know that `/usr/bin/python3` is the system python and hence should not be touched, I don't know whether it's safe to delete `/opt/homebrew/bin/python3`, `/opt/homebrew/bin/python3.10`, and `/usr/local/bin/python3.9`, since I only use conda nowadays.

Here's my thought:

- Pythons under homebrew should be okay to delete. However, I would need to redirect the missing pointer to Python under conda.
- `/usr/local/bin/python3.9`: no idea.

So my question is:

- How can I delete pythons under homebrew with a minimal amount of effort? I.e., how do I check where I use those pythons under homebrew to redirect them?
- Is it safe to delete `/usr/local/bin/python3.9`?

--Edit

After trying to uninstall pythons under homebrew, I realize that when using homebrew to install packages such as `macvim` which has a dependency on `python`, it'll just fetch it and install it with `brew`...

Comment: The only time I've seen python get installed in `/usr/local/` is when I'm doing a manual alt install built from source. My guess is that unless you've pointed applications at that installation manually, it's probably fine.

That being said, it may be part of the installation of an improperly configured package -- I'd say rename it and see if anything breaks. If something comes up not working, you know where the problem is. Maybe after a month or so, just go ahead and delete it if you don't run into any problems.

Comment: @DavidCulbreth Ah, that sounds reasonable to me. I'll do that.

Comment: Also, regarding the use of Homebrew Python:
https://justinmayer.com/posts/homebrew-python-is-not-for-you/